# Get checkbox status in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a form that has 2 checkboxes in this form. When I submit the information I want to test what the value of the first checkbox is. I use ‍‍‍‍‍‍`dd () but it shows me the value of Null. What is the problem? How can I solve this?

this is view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input class="custom-control-input" id="deposit" type="checkbox"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="deposit">Deposit</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input class="custom-control-input" id="withdraw" type="checkbox"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="withdraw">withdraw</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-round btn-outline-primary"><span class="w-100px">create</span></button>
```

and this is component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Currency;


use Livewire\Component;

class Networks extends Component
{
    
    public $deposit;
    public $withdraw;



    public function addNetwork()
    {
        dd($this->deposit1);
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.backend.currency.networks');
    }
}
```

Comment: use wire:model binding to property from the element to component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind to the checkboxes like you would any other public property, using `wire:model`.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <!-- bind to $deposit -->
        <input wire:model="deposit"
                class="custom-control-input"
                id="deposit"
                type="checkbox">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="deposit">Deposit</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <!--bind to $withdraw -->
            <input wire:model="withdraw"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    id="withdraw"
                    type="checkbox">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="withdraw">withdraw</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the form is submitted, if `deposit` or `withdraw` is `checked`, their value will be `true`.

Something you might want to do is give `$deposit` and `$withdraw` a default value of `false` as otherwise their initial values will be `null`.

```php
public $deposit = false;

public $withdraw = false;
```